# What 80s movie features a mad scientist building an inter-dimensional portal in his attic?

Tags: movie, story-identification

From what I can remember of the movie, it features an increasingly isolated loner building or inheriting **a machine in his Attic that starts bringing back monsters from outside reality when he turns it on**.  I think it was from the early 80s and it had a Lovecraftian vibe to it.  The movie is like 'The Fly' in that it features a story that slowly descends into dark horror.

Does anyone have any clue what I'm talking about?

I'll try to add more details if I can remember anymore.

Comment: Are you sure it was a movie and not an episode ala Outer Limits or Twilight Zone?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, but I was a child, so it could be one of those or a 'Tales From the Darkside' episode.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It was [*From Beyond*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/From_Beyond_%28film%29), the 1986 film based on HP Lovecraft's story of the same name.

They released an [unrated director's cut](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000RPCK2O) for this film as well.

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/70767/short-story-where-a-character-sees-another-dimension for a question about the short story

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like Stuart Gordon's [*From Beyond* (1986)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091083/) which is currently streaming on Netflix Watch Instantly.