# Short story where a character sees another dimension

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, h-p-lovecraft

I read this story years back and I can't remember its title and who wrote it.

The plot goes something like this:
A guy (or maybe some sort of scientist) gets into a lab accident(?) and his vision is impaired. He can now see things on a different plane/dimension. There are creatures there that are geometric in shape and I believe that once they notice that the guy can see them, they begin chasing him or something.

Comment: Was it a short story, novella or full novel? When is "years back", and was it new at the time? What language/nationality was it? Was it in a book, on the internet or elsewhere?

Comment: Years back being like 5 years or so ago, but the story itself is much older. It was in English. I have an inkling that it might have been written by H.G. Wells or a contemporary, but I'm not sure. Not sure if I read it in book form or digital.

Comment: It sounds vaguely like a cross between the [Hounds of Tindalos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hounds_of_Tindalos) and [From Beyond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/From_Beyond_%28short_story%29) (both part of the Cthulhu mythos.)

Comment: My guess would be for Lovecraft as well. "From Beyond" would be my guess.

Comment: Yes, that is it! *From Beyond!* I guess it wasn't an accident but some sort of machine. Mark it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It sounds like you may be crossing two stories.

HP Lovecraft's '[From Beyond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/From_Beyond_%28short_story%29)' involves a scientist creating a device that stimulate dormant senses in the human mind, allowing them to see thing from beyond this plane of existence.  Once able to be seen, they, too, can see those who see them, and things go downhill from there.  The creatures are very amorphous, and creep out the protagonist as he notices them overlapping and combining at times.  You can read it on [Wikisource](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/From_Beyond), for free. (It's long past copyright.)

I'm guessing the geometric shape aspect comes from [The Hounds of Tindalos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hounds_of_Tindalos) by Frank Belknap Long, which involves traveling back in time (mentally), and creatures that chase the protagonist back through 'strange geometries', and, specifically, can enter the world thru angles.  (The eventual victim tries to protect himself by eliminating all the angles in the room he stays in, until they get tired of the pursuit.) It, too, is on [Wikisource](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Hounds_of_Tindalos), but I'm not sure of it's copyright status, so I can't guarantee it will last.

Both are part of the Cthulhu mythos, although the first was written by Lovecraft, and the second by Long; you may well have encountered them in the same collection, tho.

Comment: There's also "The Music of Erich Zann" but it doesn't completely match the description.

Comment: The geometric entity could also be Daoloth from the Ramsey Campbell mythos story The Render of the Veils. It too can only be seen when people look into another dimension, is highly geometric, and the story could have been alongside one or both of the others you mention.

Comment: The geometric shapes detecting and chasing him in the other dimension sounds like "Dreams in the Witch House", too,