# Looking for the name of a SciFi film with a lamp that shows invisible snake-like creatures floating in the air

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

This film was a turn of the century 1900s time frame color film. It was a movie not a TV show. British I think. It was about the invention of a projector / lamp that would show creatures that were invisible floating in mid air. The creatures were snake like. The longer the projector was on the more aggressive the creatures became and eventually would have crossed over to our dimension. I can't remember the film and cant find any images on Google. May be a Lovecraft type film

Comment: Do you remember when you saw the film?

Comment: Are you sure about it taking place around the turn of the century? Because otherwise [From Beyond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/From_Beyond_(film)) might fit, and as I recall it did take place in an old house even though it was set in the 80s. The wikipedia article on [Lovecraft's story by the same name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/From_Beyond_(short_story)) also mentions there was another recent movie inspired by it, titled [Banshee Chapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banshee_Chapter), but it isn't turn of the century either.

Comment: Related: [What 80s movie features a mad scientist building an inter-dimensional portal in his attic?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1406/35)

Comment: I put my money on "From Beyond", too. I remember the scene where the big guy is literally half-eaten by those intradimensional creatures.

Comment: It was the Asphyx. Thank you all very much

Comment: @TomTreemonster - Can you select the correct answer by clicking the checkmark, so that the person who found the answer for you can be rewarded?

Comment: I actually mixed the two films together. Thank everyone for your help. Ive been looking for 40 years for this correct answer and I found it.

Comment: Was it the Asphyx or not? You've marked the other answer as correct. Actually, _From Beyond_ is 30 years old. Slightly confusing...

Comment: Yes it was the Asphys. I thought I said that above in the comments. Im having a bit pf trouble navigating this format

Comment: Tom, you said it was the Asphyx in the comments, but you seem to have clicked the check mark next to the other answer that said From Beyond. See that green check mark next to the answer? Can you click it again to unselect it, then click the check mark next to the answer with the Asphyx?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That sounds like *The Asphyx (1972)*.

The main character is a Victorian photogapher. He uses some sort of blue light when taking photographs. When photographing criminals about to be executed, the light appears to trap a creature next to the subject. He discovers that when the creature is trapped like this, the person being executed (hung) does not die. He finds a way to trap the creature and so make himself immortal. His attempts to do the same for his family are not so successful.

[imdb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0069738/)

[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Asphyx)

Answer (score 5):

You may be thinking of the 1986 movie [From Beyond,](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0091083/) :

> A group of scientists have developed the Resonator, a machine which allows whoever is within range to see beyond normal perceptible reality. But when the experiment succeeds, they are immediately attacked by terrible life forms.

It's very loosely inspired by the H.P. Lovecraft short story of the [same name.](http://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/texts/fiction/fb.aspx)